# clientWidth of element is 0 unless I set it with css

Tags: javascript, angular

How can I get an elements width **without** setting it's width property in CSS? If I set the width it works, but if I don't the width is just 0 even though I can see it's not after inspecting with debugger.

```
let width = this.htmlElement.clientWidth;
```

HTML

```
<label [model]="foobar">0</label>
```

Comment: revise your post for clear question

Comment: The label is an inline element, meaning it is only as big as it needs to be.

Comment: Does something like this help: `<label [style.width]="yourDesiredWidth"></label>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `offsetWidth` instead

```
let width = this.htmlElement.offsetWidth;
```

The first line in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) for `clientWidth` is

> The `Element.clientWidth` property **is zero for elements with no CSS** or
>   inline layout boxes, otherwise it's the inner width of an element in
>   pixels

The offsetWidth on the other hand is a read-only property that returns the *layout width* of an element, regardless of wether or not the element is styled with a given width.

```js
var el = document.getElementById('foobar');

console.log('clientWidth : '+ el.clientWidth );
console.log('offsetWidth : '+ el.offsetWidth );
```

```html
<label id="foobar">This has width ..................</label>
```

Comment: I've still got the same issue with .offsetWidth, might be to do with Angular

Comment: If you're still getting `0`, then the element has no width

Comment: it does i can see the width on the screen using chrome debugger, and there is text in <label>

Comment: And I'm telling you, if `offsetWidth` is returning `0`, it has no width. Are you sure what you're seeing isn't just overflow? Try setting `overflow : hidden` and see if you still see it, or better yet, inspect it in the console and see if has layout width.

Comment: I view the element in chrome element inspector, it highlights the element in blue and reports the dimensions 8 x 20, there is text in the element too

Comment: Then `offsetWidth` should work, it always return the actual width of the element as layed out on the page

Comment: i just tried it by using pure javascript document.getElementById('yadayada') and it works, for some reason its not working angular 2's this.element.nativeElement

Comment: I'm not that familiar with the ins and outs of Angular, but it probably returns the element wrapped in some way, even though `nativeElement` should always return the unwrapped node ?