# .clientwidth returns 0 in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

Could someone point out why is `.clientWidth` returns 0 in Chrome, IE and works just fine in Firefox?

Here is my code:

```
const sliderRowItems = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-row img");
const size = sliderRowItems[0].clientWidth;
```

```
<div class="slider-row">
     <img class="lastSlide" src="/images/img5.jpg" alt="">
     <img class="" src="/images/img1.jpg" alt="">
     <img class="" src="/images/img2.jpg" alt="">
     <img class="" src="/images/img3.jpg" alt="">
     <img class="" src="/images/img4.jpg" alt="">
     <img class="" src="/images/img5.jpg" alt="">
     <img class="firstSlide" src="/images/img1.jpg" alt=""></div>
</div>
```

[The whole thing](https://jsfiddle.net/vs5pmdby/)

Comment: Similar:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133069/clientwidth-and-clientheight-returns-0, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45260088/clientwidth-of-element-is-0-unless-i-set-it-with-css

Comment: Could you please reproduce the issue?. Because it is working properly for me. Please check the chrome version, `clientWidth` is supported in chrome for versions above `43`.  https://caniuse.com/#search=clientWidth, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth.

Comment: My version is 80.
It worked fine for me  too when I tried to use it separately. Here is my whole thing https://jsfiddle.net/vs5pmdby/. I think the problem is somwhere else.

Answer (score 0):

In your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vs5pmdby/) you're trying to access already gathered `nodeList` from the `document` as if it was its property:

```
const sliderRowItems = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-row img");
let doc = document;

// that's the line causing problems, it even errors out in the console
const size = doc.sliderRowItems[0].clientWidth;
```

Just delete `doc.` from that line.